# Eclipse IDE with Kotlin plugin terminates with code 1 however no error message is displayed

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I'm trying to run the following:

```kotlin
data class Category(
    /** Unique ID of a category */
    val id: Long,
    /** Name of the category */
    val name: Int,
    /** Category's image resource id */
    val image: Int
)

object LocalCategoriesDataProvider {
    val allCategories = listOf(
        Category(
            id = 0L,
            name = 1,
            image = 1
        ),
        Category(
            id = 1L,
            name = 2,
            image = 2
        ),
        Category(
            id = 2L,
            name = 3,
            image = 3
        ),
        Category(
            id = 3L,
            name = 4,
            image = 4
        )
    )
}

fun main() {
    val aList = listOf("1", "2", "3")
    println(aList[0])
    

    /**
     * Returns [Category] based on id
     */
    fun getCategoryById(categoryId: Long): Category {
        return LocalCategoriesDataProvider.allCategories.firstOrNull { it.id == categoryId }
            ?: LocalCategoriesDataProvider.allCategories.first()
    }
    val defaultCategory = getCategoryById(0)
    println("default category is: ${defaultCategory}")
}
```

however, the console contains `1` as output. It seems this is the exit code of the program as Eclipse runs it.

How can I see the error message associated with it?

Note that I'm running Kotlin with Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24. `Problems` tab is empty.

---

Screenshot:

[image: Eclipse IDE Kotlin error code 1]

Comment: Be sure to use the [Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-kotlin-eclipse)

Comment: Yep, it's installed. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out JDK configuration was missing. I installed `openjdk-17-jdk` with `apt install openjdk-17-jdk` and then, in Eclipse, I went to Window > Preferences > Kotlin > Compiler and typed in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64` in JDK Home field. Applied & Closed, ran again and it worked.